# How to open a new workbook and add images with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get a macro for Excel 2007to open a folder with a bunch of images in them. Then Create a new workbook and embed the images into it.

Everything works if I comment out the line `Sheet.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:=F, linktofile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=cell.Left + 5, Top:=cell.Top + 5, Width:=560, Height:=310` If I uncomment that line I get "Run-time error '434': Object required"

I've check that Sheet.Shapes is returning a Shapes object, it is but the Shapes object is empty. When I try Sheet.Shapes,AddPicture on a workbook that is opened outside of the macro, it adds the images. I've also checked that Sheet.Shapes.AddShape works with the workbook opened in the macro, it does.

At this point, I'm at a lose for what the issue might be. Does anyone have any experience with this sort of thing? Should I be using a different method? Thanks in advance for any help or guidance.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim ImagePath, Flist
ImagePath = GetFolder()
If ImagePath = "" Then Exit Sub
Flist = FileList(ImagePath)
Name = "C:\target.xlsm"
Set Book = Workbooks.Add
Set Sheet = Book.Sheets(1)
For i = 1 To 5
    cell = "C" + CStr(i)
    F = ImagePath + "\" + Flist(i - 1)
        Sheet.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:=F, linktofile:=msoFalse, _
            savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=cell.Left + 5, Top:=cell.Top + 5, Width:=560, Height:=310
    Next
Book.SaveAs FileName:=Name, FileFormat:=52
Book.Close
End Sub

 Function FileList(ByVal fldr As String) As Variant
'Lists all the files in the current directory
'Found at http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=71409
    Dim sTemp As String, sHldr As String
    If Right$(fldr, 1) <> "\" Then fldr = fldr & "\"
    sTemp = Dir(fldr & "*.png")
    If sTemp = "" Then
        FileList = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    Do
        sHldr = Dir
        If sHldr = "" Then Exit Do
        sTemp = sTemp & "|" & sHldr
    Loop
    FileList = Split(sTemp, "|")
End Function

Function GetFolder() As String
Folder:
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "New Screenshot Folder"
    .Show
    num = .SelectedItems.Count
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        GetFolder = ""
    Else: GetFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With
End Function
```

Comment: you are using a variable named **Name**, **cell** and other reserved names, and this wil lead to errors for sure. I suggest always leading your variable names with a variable identifier, like **i** if it is an integer, **s** if it is a string, etc. so that you assure they are not using reserved names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't define a cell by creating the string "C1", that's just the address. The way you did it, `cell` is a string and a string doesn't have any properties. What you want is a range object so either use

```
Dim cell As Range
Set cell = sheet.Range("C" & i)
```

or

```
Dim cell As Range
Set cell = sheet.Cells(i, 3)
```

You should always `Dim` all variables, use `Option Explicit` on top of your module so you don't forget it ;)

This will often prevent mistakes. Of course you should `Dim` them with the correct type, i.e. `Dim FilePath As String`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct command would be:

```
        Sheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=F, linktofile:=msoFalse, _
        savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, Left:=Range(cell).Left + 5, Top:=Range(cell).Top + 5, Width:=560, Height:=310
```

I strongly advise you to change your **Name** variable name, as it will cause errors on recent versions of excel.

Comment: When will using `Name` as a variable cause an error? I agree that it shouldn't be used as a variable but as long as it's used correctly (as a string variable) it should still work?

Comment: I can tell that in excel 2016 **Name** is reserved. Using this as a variable will result in a runtime error '1004'.

Comment: Weird, I am using Excel 2016 and can use `Name` just like any other variable. I can even use something like `ActiveCell` as a string variable without causing an error (unless I try to use the actual `ActiveCell` object of course). Maybe an option I haven't set?

Comment: Try it without Dim'ming Name. Instead of changing a variable you will end up changing your sheet´s name :)

Comment: It just creates a `Variant/String` type variable for me when I don't Dim it.